# Mercurial autosync user

Tags: mercurial

I have an internal mercurial web server that is served using IIS, using window security, and another server on my external web server set up the same way.

Developers commit code to the internal server, and teamcity builds from there.

However we are now working on a customer portal on the web site that can list some mercurial information. This connects to the local instance of mercurial (i.e. the one on the external server)

I have installed the mercurial autosync plug-in onto the internal server, with the intention of updating the master copy of the code on the external server, and allowing the website to read it's information from there. Code will never be checked in directly to the external server, all updates will come from the internal server. All repositories are clones of the ones on the external server.

I have run the autosync command in the repositories on the internal server "hg autosync -D" and I have tried it with "hg autosync -D -u username" but when I check the autosync log all I see is this:

------------------------------ 06/08/12 08:54:56 ------------------------------
sync: commit working copy changes
nothing changed
sync: fetch changes from other repository
http authorization required
realm: www.mydomain.co.uk
user: response expected
sync: an error occurred, will retry at next interval

anyone have any idea how to specify the user (and password?) correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add credentials to the `C:\Users\<username>\mercurial.ini` file of the user running Mercurial:

```
[auth]
mydomain.prefix = mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.username = <username>
mydomain.password = <password>
```

Comment: I managed to work this out myself in the mean time but thank you. As it happened, because I am also using mercurial through IIS, I needed to modify hgweb.config rather than mercurial.ini. 

Also, my only question with this solution is this:
Rather than have just mydomain.com I have mydomain.com/mercurial/projectname as the prefix property. As such I have created duplicate entries for my other projects. Could I use your example to specify credentials for the entire server?

Comment: @MarkJones Check out the [Mercurial docs on auth settings](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth).  If you set `mydomain.prefix` to `*`, those credentials will apply to all servers that don't match another auth prefix.

Comment: And as a result, you risk that your (secret) credentials are sent to arbitrary external servers (not so secret). Better to at the least list the domains explicitly. They should then indeed apply to all paths underneath it.